# Rectangle base corner and corner at the cursor does not preserver their location, see video

Tags: fabricjs

The base point of the rectangle is not preserved after moving the mouse. Also, the 2nd corner of the rectangle does not stick with the mouse. Please see [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzvu6k2gbku0qm6/FabricjsRectangleBug.mov?dl=0) or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7mad24/aPLq5/).

Expected Behavior

Base point always remains at the some coordinate. The 2nd point always sticks with the mouse cursor.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var rect, isDown, origX, origY;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
isDown = true;
var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
origX = pointer.x;
origY = pointer.y;
var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: origX,
    top: origY,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    width: pointer.x-origX,
    height: pointer.y-origY,
    angle: 0,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    transparentCorners: false
});
canvas.add(rect);
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
if (!isDown) return;
var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

if(origX>pointer.x){
    rect.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
}
if(origY>pointer.y){
    rect.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
}

rect.set({ width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
rect.set({ height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) });


canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
isDown = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following code in mouse move listener which changes the top and left of the rectangle to always keep the basepoint at the same place.

```
 /*if(origX>pointer.x){
        rect.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
    }
    if(origY>pointer.y){
        rect.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
    }*/
```

Overall I find the second point sticks with the mouse cursor unless you move the cursor really really fast.

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aPLq5/333/